# How to access item in Viewbag created in a certain controller and use it in another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an item in a `ViewBag` from a HomeController like this.

`ViewBag.RMessage = "You have been redirected to Login Page";`

and I want to access it from my Login.cshtml.

Is that possible? if yes, how?

Comment: You need to TempData keep method to retain the value for the next controller action.
Take a look at this URL.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ansh06031982/using-tempdata-peek-and-keep-in-Asp-Net-mvc/
https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/mvc-when-to-use-keep-vs-peek-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @ThomsonMixab It does not work sir. After calling the method Keep on my current Action. The redirection of page from `MainPage.cshtml` to `LoginPage.cshtml` clears all the keys and values in TempData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session like following:

In your `startup`,you can add:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSession();

        //....
    }
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseSession();
        //...
     }
```

Then in your `Homecontroller`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //set session

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("RMessage", "You have been redirected to Login Page");
        return View();
    }
    }
```

Then in your `Login` view,you can get it by:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

//...
RMessage: @Context.Session.GetString("RMessage")
```

About more details,you can see the doc:[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this but I thought it was a bad practice to store just a message in session state. So I removed it. Again, Thank you.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia You were right. It is a bad practice to use session at all, and for messages escpecially. It is better to try TempData , but is not very good too. the better way to send it with request together.

Comment: You can also pass this value step by step, pass it to the view and use asp-route-para="@ViewBag.RMessage", and then use it in the background
 public IActionResult Index(string para) to accept.